# Error with rosbag record

Tags: ros, rosbag, turtlebot, camera-depth-points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to record any topic with rosbag, such as:

```
rosbag record /camera/depth/points
```

I get this error:

```
Error writing: Error opening file: 2012-07-06-11-13-31.bag.active
```

**Possibly extraneous info**: I'm running this on my laptop that is physically attached to my turtlebot and I know for a fact that the topics I'm trying to subscribe to are being published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38108/error-with-rosbag-record/) by [atmiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2640/atmiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atmiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2640/atmiguel/) on 2012-07-06**:
wow i feel silly. I was trying to do this in my ros workspace where apparently i don't have permissions. it worked perfectly in my home directory. Thanks allenh1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. This could be a couple things. You didn't finish a bag file, so fix the bag:

```
rosbag reindex 2012-07-06-11-13-31.bag.active
```

To take the bag file and make it record to a different name, try this:

```
rosbag record /camera/depth/points -O Camera.bag
```

The first command makes the bag file playable (the laptop probably shut down in the middle of a run).

The second one tells rosbag to record to a different file name.

This could also be a problem with your version of rosbag. Which rosbag are you using? Which OS? Ros version?

Or, you could be recording your bag file in a place you don't have write permissions. Try recording it in the home directory.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1